# Unable to initialize the data frame values into a variable

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to Map the date frame column values from one data frame into another data frame.  I have initialized the column values for each row each row into a variable and assign the variable into the new data frame

I am trying to map the row values into a new data frame.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
chat_df_format = pd.DataFrame(columns=['sender_name', 'message_content'])
# loop through the rows using iterrows()

for idx, row in chat_df.iterrows():
    if (row.check_numnber == True):
         chat_meta_data = row.message_details
    else:
        chat_content = row.message_details
        chat_df_format.at[idx,'sender_name'] = chat_meta_data
        chat_df_format.at[idx,'message_content'] = chat_content

display(chat_df_format)
```

I am getting the below error [image]

Comment: The error is self-explanatory. In the first row, `check_numnber` is `False`, and so `chat_meta_data` does not get set, but you then try and use it in the `else` clause.

Comment: instead of `if (row.check_number == True)` you could simply use `if row.check_number`

I'm guessing `chat_meta_data` should have a initial value that will change if the codition is true. so perhaps you missed the initialization.